# PROLOG [hand computation]

Tags: prolog

I am trying to practice hand computations in prolog could you please explain to me and demonstrate a hand computation of this certain question so I can gain more of an understanding.

In a Prolog project involving text processing (not discussed here further) a predicate duplicate/2 has been implemented for duplicating every entry of a list. 
Below is an example of what duplicate/2 does:

```
?- duplicate([w,o,r,d], D).

D = [w,w,o,o,r,r,d,d] .

?- duplicate([], D).

D = [].
```

below shows the definition of duplicate/2 . Write down hand computations for duplicate/2

```
duplicate(L, D) :- duplicate(L,[], D). % clause 0

duplicate([], Acc, D) :- reverse(Acc, D). % clause 1

duplicate([H|T], Acc, D) :- duplicate(T, [H, H|Acc], D). % clause 2
```

(involving the auxiliary predicate duplicate/3 ) such that each of the three 
clauses (numbered 0, 1, 2), is performed in the hand computations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well let's go for a reduced version of your example query `duplicate([w], D).`
. There's only one rule head, which takes two arguments: the one of clause 0, with L=[w] and D1=D.(1) The body tells us, we should derive `duplicate([w],[],D)` instead. The head of clause 1 does not match, because [] and [w] cannot be unified. This leaves clause 2: [w] = [H|T] unifies with H=w and T=[] (2), Acc = [] and D2=D. Now our new goal is `duplicate([], [w,w], D)`, which only matches against clause 1 (3). Our goal there is `reverse([w,w],D)`, which is the builtin [reverse/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=reverse/2) predicate. It is true if D unifies with the reverse list of [w,w], therefore D=[w,w]. Now we don't have any goals to derive and have found a full derivation. Since we always renamed the rule's variables, the D is still the one from our original query, meaning that D = [w,w] is a correct answer substitution for the query.

I admit I was a bit lazy, with only one duplicated letter, the reversal of the accumulator Acc seems a little pointless. To see why it is necessary, you can try the same derivation for `duplicate([x,y],D)`, where the accumulator should be [y,y,x,x] since the elements are always prepended.

Another interesting exercise is also `duplicate(X,[w,w])` and to check why `duplicate(X,[w])` fails (Hint: look at the unification problem [w] = [H,H|Acc] ). What's also not contained so far is backtracking: in the case of the query `duplicate(X, Y)`, your goal matches multiple heads and you get more than one solution (actually an infinite number of them).

Have fun playing around!

(1) A rule is true independent of how exactly its variables are named. When we have two variables of the same name D from different rules, we need to rename the D in one of the rules to something else, say D1.

(2) You can check this on the prompt by entering the unification as a query:

```
1 ?- [w] = [H|T].
H = w,
T = [].
```

(3) The reason is that the list [H|T] has at least one element, whereas [] doesn't have one. You can again check this on the prompt:

```
2 ?- [] = [H|T].
false.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you allow the computer to help you in hand computation there are two classical approaches to do that:

1) Use a debugger: Most of the Prolog debuggers use the Byrd box model, means it only shows you a selected goal in the process of a resolution proof. Here is a run of a smaller query for a simpler program. Usually the debugger can be switched on by trace:

```
?- [user].
duplicate([], []).
duplicate([X|Y], [X,X|Z]) :- duplicate(Y,Z).
^D
Yes
?- duplicate([w,o],X).
X = [w,w,o,o]
?- trace.
Yes 
?- duplicate([w,o],X).
    0 Call duplicate([w,o], X) ?
    1 Call duplicate([o], _C) ?
    2 Call duplicate([], _F) ?
    2 Exit duplicate([], []) ?
    1 Exit duplicate([o], [o,o]) ?
    0 Exit duplicate([w,o], [w,w,o,o]) ?
X = [w,w,o,o] ;
    0 Redo duplicate([w,o], [w,w,o,o]) ?
    1 Redo duplicate([o], [o,o]) ?
    2 Redo duplicate([], []) ?
    2 Fail duplicate([], _F) ?
    1 Fail duplicate([o], _C) ?
    0 Fail duplicate([w,o], X) ?
No
```

2) Write a meta interpreter: You can write meta interpreters that deliver a trace, which can be inspected after a run and which give a certificate of the proof the Prolog system found:

This is the normal vanilla interpreter:

```
solve(true) :- !.
solve((A,B)) :- !, solve(A), solve(B).
solve(A) :- rule(A,B), solve(B).
```

Here is an interpreter that gives a trace of the applied 
clauses, its implemented in DCG:

```
solve(true) --> [].
solve((A,B)) --> !, solve(A), solve(B).
solve(A) --> {rule(A,B)}, [(A :- B)], solve(B).
```

Here is an example run for the simplified duplicate query and program again:

```
rule(duplicate([], []), true).
rule(duplicate([X|Y], [X,X|Z]), duplicate(Y,Z)).

?- solve(duplicate([w,o],X),L,[]).
X = [w,w,o,o],
L = [(duplicate([w,o],[w,w,o,o]) :- duplicate([o],[o,o])),
     (duplicate([o],[o,o]) :- duplicate([],[])),
     (duplicate([],[]) :- true)]
```

Bye

Answer (score 1):

`duplicate(L, D) :- duplicate(L,[], D). % clause 0`

`duplicate([], Acc, D) :- reverse(Acc, D). % clause 1`

`duplicate([H|T], Acc, D) :- duplicate(T, [H, H|Acc], D). % clause 2`

**quick hand computation below for my understanding please correct me if im wrong and tell me if i am correct because i am new to prolog.**

`duplicate[w,o,r,d], D) clause 0 --> duplicate ([w,o,r,d],[].D). 
clause 2 --> duplicate[w,o,r,d],Acc,D) --> clause 2 duplicate([o,r,d],[w,w],[],D),`

i could keep going through clause 2 to keep duplicating the head of the list , i can do this till the list is empty []. then i can move to clause 1.

which i can then put my list in the accumulator then reverse it to produce [d,d,r,r,o,o,w,w]

**below is the hand computation of clause 1.**

`clause 1 duplicate[w,w,o,o,r,r,d,d],D) ---> clause 1 reverse([w,w,o,o,r,r,d,d],D).`

D = [d,d,r,r,o,o,w,w]

Comment: Yes, that's how this predicate works. In the general case, you might need to satisfy a list of goals. Take for example: 1: a(X, f(X)).  2: b(g). 3: c(X) :- b(Y), a(Y,X). Then the query c(X) resolves with 3 to: b(Y), a(Y,X). The next goal is b(Y), so we resolve with 2 and the substiution Y=g, leaving the goal: a(g, X). Renaming the X in 1 to X0 and substituting X0 = g, X=f(g), we can resolve with the last goal. Now we insert back into the query and obtain X=f(g) as the answer substitution.